# Generically add field to anonymous record using a function

Tags: f#, anonymous-types

I would like to be able to take an arbitrary record as a parameter and return an anonymous record with a field added using the copy-and-update syntax.

For example, this works:

```ml
let fooBar =
  {| Foo = ()
     Bar = () |}

let fooBarBaz = {| fooBar with Baz = () |}
```

But I would like to do this:

```ml
let fooBar =
  {| Foo = ()
     Bar = () |}

let inline addBaz a = {| a with Baz = () |} (* The input to a copy-and-update expression that creates an anonymous record must be either an anonymous record or a record *)

let fooBarBaz = addBaz fooBar
```

Is there a way to do this in F#?

Comment: Not part of the current answers, but in .NET you can emit assemblies dynamically, and load them. So, the above is possible, just not statically, or easily. Depending on your use case, consider also Type Providers, code generation, or dynamic types (similar to the C# feature).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Think about it, if that function was possible, what would be the type ?
Is it something that "fits" into existing F# type system?

The type should be something like `val addField: x: {| FieldName<1>: 't1; FieldName<2>: 't2; ... FieldName<n>: 'tn;|} -> {| FieldName<1>: 't1; FieldName<2>: 't2; ... FieldName<n>: 'tn;  Baz: unit |}`

Clearly something like that's not representable in F# type system.

**UPDATE**

It was mentioned that adding a record constraint would allow this but this is quite far from reality. A record constraint would just filter the argument to be a record but the problem which remains is how do the type system express that the function takes a type `^T when ^T : record` and returns something like `^U when ^U : ^T_butWithAnAdditionalField`

Also, on the SRTP side there is a way to "read" a field by adding a `get_FieldName` constraint but not to write, moreover the possibility to read a field allow us to read a field of a known name, not any name.

Conclusion: F# type system is very far away from allowing to express stuff like this and the SRTP mechanism is not there either.

Allowing an "is record" constraint shouldn't be that complicated but it won't solve anything here.

Comment: Could you clarify? I can make a function, for example, of signature `{| Foo: int |} -> {| Bar: int; Foo: int |}`. I'm wondering why I can't make a generic `inline` version, perhaps restraining the fields using SRTPs.

Comment: How would the SRTP signature look like ?

Comment: As Tom said, I would need to be able to verify that the argument is a record. I would like to be able to limit the argument type by field name as I can by member name.

Comment: Read my comments. That's not enough. You need to specify the whole type transformation in a generic way.

Comment: Do you mean that I would need to specify field types as well as names? I would be fine with that.

Comment: Kind of, you'll have to tell somehow  that there will be an additional field. I wrote an update, have a look. I hope it clarifies a bit the situation.

Comment: The return type is not defined! That's an excellent point. Thank you. Upvoting.

Comment: I disagree. The return type is defined. We can mechanically say what it is, so can the compiler. It is the anonymous record that has all fields from the input record with Baz replaced or added with type unit.

Comment: Is it defined? Where? How would like that signature? Can you either point to where is it defined or write a sample signature, valid within the current type system plus the record constraint addition?

Comment: I understand your point now, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. You can find a discussion about it in this proposal:

> [#807](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/807): Allow record to be a generic constraint

If I understand correctly, the solution they mention in the proposal is that you have to be able to constrain the input type to be record. Something that is currently not possible.

But as Gus points out in his answer, a second consideration is that you also need to have a way to specify the output type because the output type depends on the input type.

UPDATE:

There is some discussion going on whether the linked to proposal is relevant or not or if the conclusion I draw from it it correct. First of all, I do not work on the compiler, so I don't know what the biggest hurdle would be. But below analysis does not seem unreasonable to me.

First, let's get rid of generics to have a feel for what's going on:

```
type Foo = 
  { Foo: int }

let addBaz (x: Foo) = // Foo -> {| Baz: unit; Foo: int|}
  {| x with Baz = () |}
```

This compiles and works as expected and does pretty much what is asked, *but without the input argument being generic*.

A few things to note:

- There is no need to explicitly define the output type.
- There is no need for a dynamic type system.

Because the compiler can infer the type definition from the code: an anonymous record with all fields from the input type `Foo` and the additional `Baz` field with unit type (this would also work if `Foo` already had a Baz field in which case it would be replaced).

If we make it generic we get the following compilation error

```
let addBaz (x: 'a) =
      {| x with Baz = () |}
```

> FS3245: The input to a copy-and-update expression that creates an anonymous record must be either an anonymous record or a record

And that makes sense, because there is no way to say that x is a record. We could give it a class or just an int.

So, assuming we could constrain the input to be a record, could this in theory work?

Let's check a few cases by deducing types as the compiler would do for some examples:

```
type Foo = 
  { Foo: int }

type BazInt =
  { Baz: int }

type BazUnit =
  { Baz: unit }

type MoreFields =
  { Bar: string
    Foo: int }

let addBaz (x: BazInt) =
  {| x with Baz = () |}

let test () =
  let foo` = addBaz { Foo = 5 } // OK: addBaz monomorphizes* to `Foo -> {| Baz: unit; Foo: int |}`
  let bazInt` = addBaz { BazInt.Baz = 5 } // OK: addBaz monomorphizes* to `BazInt -> {| Baz: unit |}`
  let bazUnit` = addBaz { BazUnit.Baz = () } // OK: addBaz monomorphizes* to `BazUnit -> {| Baz: unit |}`
  let moreFields` = addBaz { MoreFields.Foo = 1; MoreFields.Bar = "" } // OK: addBaz monomorphizes* to `MoreFields -> {| Bar: string; Baz: unit; Foo: int |}`
```

*: I used [monomorphization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphization) because it's the terminology I know from C++ templates, I'm not sure if .net uses the same terminology. But AFAIK, it doesn't matter for this discussion and the idea is the same: you just replace the generic input type `'a` with the concrete type used where the function is called.

UPDATE 2:

I now get what Gus points to with the return type. The problem isn't that it can't be deduced as I showed. The problem is that somehow you need to show the generic output type. Something that currently isn't possible in F#. The return type only becomes 'complete' when it the function is called. In C++ this is perfectly fine, but in F# it isn't.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. That proposal won't allow to generically add fields as specified in the question. On top of that you'll need a way to specify field names in a generic way, which is currently not supported and that proposal doesn't cover it. See my answer.

Comment: You could disagree with proposal being correct, but it states its intent very clearly: `allow the conversion and extension of any anonymous record by adding a foo field`. For me that matches up pretty close with what was asked.

Comment: Well, that's not the title of the proposal, nor included in the description of what can you define. It is wrongly stated that as a consequence of this addition it would allow to add fields, but if you follow the discussion it becomes clear that assumption is wrong.

Comment: Also, you say "the main issue is that you have to be able to constrain the input type to be record", sorry but that's not the main issue. That's relatively easy to add, the complicated part is to "upgrade" the type system to be able to represent the type of the function that adds a field to a record in a generic way.

Comment: The intro of that proposal says the following exact quote: "this would allow the conversion and *extension* of any anon record in the following way
'let inline appendFoo < ^X when ^X : record> (x: ^X) myFoo = {| x with foo = myFoo |}'. Remove the annotations and use unit as myFoo this becomes `let inline appendFoo x = {| a with Foo = () |}`. You can't seriously say that this is not what OP is asking.

Comment: Yes, that's a conclusion he draws incorrectly. Having a record constraint won't be enough. We have `struct` constraints already and that doesn't allow us to express a struct transformation in a generic way, even with SRTPs.

Comment: @Gus I accepted this answer because it gives a valid reason why I can't do what I want to do, which is what I asked. I'm still listening to you as well.

Comment: It's always to good to accept answers, but please edit the text of the answer as it seems inaccurate and in this case it's very likely many users will get confused. Then I'm happy to delete my answer.

Comment: @Gus Please don't delete your answer unless you feel it entirely redundant. It looks to me as though it adds useful information.

Comment: There’s a misunderstanding in this discussion. The OP asks to dynamically expand the fields of a record, any record, given not as type but as value. This answer suggests you’d need a `record` constraint. While somewhat related, these are two different things. What you need is a dynamic typing system, which doesn’t exist.

Comment: This answer says “the main issue is that you have to be able to constrain the input type to be record”. But the main issue is to expand a value of type record with a new field. I agree with @Gus that this answer is just wrong. Sorry to be blunt, misunderstandings happen ;).

Comment: Your updated answer is an improvement, but you’re missing the point that the CLR doesn’t allow generic types to be expanded (.NET limitation). So, the only solution could be with SRTP, so that the extension is expressible and can statically be type checked and compiled. This *may be* possible in a far future, but this kind of *ducktyping* is certainly not supported, and there’s no RFC or other proposal that covers this. But who knows, maybe in the future.